# How was sadism viewed(if at all) in philosophy before Marquis de Sade?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

Were there any preceding philosophers who wrote about concepts that were roughly equivalent to sadism?

Comment: Was he actually a philosopher?

Comment: I have very little knowledge of his work but I suppose you could call him that.

Comment: @AmeetSharma at the very least Wikipedia considers him as one: "Donatien Alphonse François, Marquis de Sade, was a French nobleman, revolutionary politician, **philosopher**, and writer, famous for his libertine sexuality."

Comment: De Sade did have a philosophy, a medley of atheism, anarchism, sensual hedonism, libertinism and moral nihilism, but that is not what is called "sadism". Some elements of it can be detected in others, before and after, e.g. [ancient cynics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynicism_(philosophy)) and [cyrenaics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrenaics), but his mix is quite unique in its radicalism. An academic work on his philosophy is [Airaksinen, The Philosophy of the Marquis de Sade](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Philosophy_of_the_Marquis_de_Sade.html?id=MqyIAgAAQBAJ).

Comment: @AmeetSharma: He is definitely *of philosophical significance* - DeBouvoir wrote a famous and compelling introduction to 120 Days Of Sodom. His book Justine certainly presents a challenge to consequentualist ethicists too, suggesting bad times & societies may require bad behaviour, for a person to flourish

Comment: What DeSade was doing in his works is more complex, or at least more enigmatic than they appear. His books were all illegal, and have to understood as part of subversive libertine culture, under a system of tight control of printing and expression. He was 49 when the French Revolution happened, & though aristocratic profoundly disillusioned with a society & regime difficult for us to imagine. This event happened just before his birth https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Cat_Massacre & gives useful insight into inequality, social immobility, & enthusiastic cathartic cruelty of the era

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question open to a number of answers. I am not aware of 'preceding philosophers who wrote about concepts that were roughly equivalent to sadism'. This may, however, show just the limitation of my knowledge. What I offer below does not, then, answer your question but it does suggest (what I hope os next best) that philosophers were aware, before de Sade, of a Sadean approach to life through the example of de Rais.

Philosophers and others would, however, have been aware of a kind of pre-Sadean sadist in the figure of Gilles de Rais (1405-40).

> What influence ... led de Sade to imagine atrocities
>    he could never have practised ? The answer ... lay in his reading. 
>   De Sade had enjoyed
>    Suetonius's lives of the Roman emperors and revelled in
>    the cruelties of those days. But above all he had been
>    fascinated by the shocking cruelty and unbridled sexual
>    abnormalities of Gilles de Rais.
>    Gilles de Rais, Marshal of France, born more than three
>    centuries earlier than de Sade in 1404, was like him in his
>    wealth, his aristocratic origin, and his personal bravery.
>    Like de Sade also he had studied the lives of the Roman
>    emperors. But de Rais was a sadist in the fullest sense of
>    that term.
>
> As a young man Gilles de Rais had earned a good name
>    for his behaviour at court, and when in 1429 Joan of Arc
>    had appeared there he supported her cause. He went further
>    still. He was her squire at Orleans, where, although wounded,
>   he saved Joan from capture. For this, at 25, he was accorded
>    the unparalleled military honour for his age of being made
>    Marshal of France. When later, in consequence of the
>    king's half-hearted support, Joan of Arc was finally taken,
>    Gilles de Rais set forth again and laid siege to Rouen.
>    Indeed, Joan's martyrdom was probably the turning-point
>    of his life. Leaving the army and court in disgust, Gilles
>    de Rais and a boon companion embarked on a career of
>    seduction and cruel murder of boys. The children were
>    taken to his castle in Normandy, where they were killed
>    slowly by slitting their abdomens or by strangulation during
>    sexual orgies; others were sacrificed for the purposes of
>    black magic. More than 200 such murders were committed
>    before Gilles de Rais was arrested and hanged in 1440.
>    Gilles de Rais, it was said, was the original of the Normandy
>    legend of Bluebeard.

('Sadism And Power: A Physician On De Sade', The British Medical Journal, Vol. 1, No. 5014 (Feb. 9, 1957), pp. 337-338: 337-8.)

I suggest that de Rais, who can be seen as a proto-sadist, may have occupied a place in the moral imagination of philosophers as a paradigm of evil.